# Javascript delete after last character of his kind

Tags: javascript

I have a string with a bunch of values like `aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff`. The length is always different.

I need to the remove the last value without the `,` so it should be like:

```
aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee,
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Share your code what ever you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `lastIndexOf` for such cases:

```js
var str = "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff";
var newStr = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(',')+1);
console.log(newStr)

var str2 = "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff,";
var newStr2 = str2.substring(0, str2.lastIndexOf(',')+1);
console.log(newStr2)
```

---

#### Edit

As per @[RomanPerekhrest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185459/romanperekhrest)'s comment, if we want to replace last valid value (*comma followed by characters*), you can try something like this.

```js
var str = "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff,,,,";
var regex = /(?!,)(.\w+)/g;
var lastMatch = str.match(regex).pop();
var finalStr = str.split(lastMatch)[0]
console.log(finalStr)
```

Comment: what if a string is `aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff,` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest OP has not confirmed the behaviour for cases.

Comment: @Damon, can you please suggest behaviour for this case?

Comment: @Rajesh well this seems perfect, because this case could happen too

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have updated my answer. Hope it serves your concern. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods.

```js
var str = 'aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff.';

// split string by separator ,
var s = str.split(',');
// update the last element in the array
s[s.length - 1] = '';
// join it back again
console.log(
  s.join(',')
)
```

---

or using [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```js
var str = 'aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff.';

// remove any combination which doesn't include ,
console.log(
  str.replace(/[^,]+$/, '')
)
```

Comment: Isn't `lastIndexOf` more suited for such cases?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to do that:

```
"aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff".replace(/[^,]+$/, "");
```

Here I replace as much possible characters `+` that are not `,` : `[^,]` and are at the end of the string: `$`

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```js
var str = "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee";
var arr = str.split(' ');
if (arr[arr.length -1].indexOf(',') > -1) {
    arr.pop();
}
var newStr = arr.join(' ');
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the last word and the whitespace before.

```js
var string = 'aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff';
console.log(string.replace(/\s+\w+$/, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff";
str = str.substr(0,str.lastIndexOf(",")+1) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by splitting the string and then join.

```
var old_string = "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff";
//transform it into a array
var array_string = old_string.split(',');
//removing the last index
array_string.pop();
//make it a string again
var new_string = array_string.join(',');
alert(new_string);
```